# Why my iAds ads corrupted on iPads

Tags: ios, iad

On iPhone all ok. On iPads iAds ads looks like corrupted. But when it loads new ads (blue, red etc..) all looks great. Where is my mistake?

```
// in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        adsBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, winSize.height - 66, 768, 66)];
    }
    else
    {
        adsBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, winSize.height - 50, 320, 50)];
    }

// somewhere in AppDelegate

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:banner];
}
```

Here is image from iPad with corrupted ads:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with iPad. Why are you initializing the `ADBannerView` like this? You are not using the API correctly. Use the designated initializer method `initWithAdType:` to get the correct result (you most likely need to use `ADAdTypeBanner` as the type).

To resize to fit to a specific view, you need to use what is recommended [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Content_Size_Identifiers).